# What does double dots .. mean in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-schema

I am using SQL Server. I found the following way to backup a database table:

```
-- Taking a backup    
SELECT * INTO MY_BACKUP_DATABASE..CustomersTemporaryTable FROM Customers
```

I am trying to understand the `..` in the syntax. From what I understand, the sentence means that `Customers` is the table that is going to be backed-up by placing it all of its content into the database called `MY_BACKUP_DATABASE` using `CustomersTemporaryTable` as the destination table. I assume when executing the sentence, `CustomersTemporaryTable` must already exist. Is my understanding of the sentence to take a backup correct?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The explanation for `..` syntax? (Default schema notation) Or the `INTO` syntax and whether it creates a table? (Yes, the table must *not* exist) Or whether this is a good way to create a backup of a whole database? (Not normally, can use it for a single table)

Comment: @Charlieface I was mainly confused about the `..` notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each MS SQL Table identifiers can have a name compound of three parts separates with a dot :

- the database name
- the SQL schema name (by default dbo)
- the table, view or Table UDF name

Syntax :

```
db_name.schema_name.table_name
```

But it is not always necessary to specify the three parts.

Inside the current database, no need to specify the db_name. It's implicit...
By default every SQL user is associate with a specific default schema (frequently dbo too...).

So you can specify a table name with :

```
schema_name.table_name
```

...SQL Server will try to find the table into the current DB

```
db_name..table_name
```

...SQL Server will try to find the table into the specified DB and the default user schema

```
table_name
```

...SQL Server will try to find the table into the current DB and the
default user schema

To know with SQL schema is associated with your SQL user, use :

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME() AS DEFAULT_CURRENT_USER_SCHEMA
```

To know all the associations between SQL users and SQL schemas, do :

```
SELECT name AS USER_NAME, default_schema_name
FROM   sys.database_principals
WHERE  type_desc LIKE '%?_USER' ESCAPE '?'
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, understand that what you are doing is not "taking a backup", it is inserting data into a table from another table. If you have not created the destination table the syntax is like this:

Select *
INTO Destination_Table
FROM Source_Table

The destination table will be created automatically. This doesn't necessarily work so well if you will be inserting additional data that might be different lengths or data types, but for a one of select should work fine.